# Dont show field if blank Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In my rails table i have a `text_field` which `my_website`, so <%= f.text_field :my_website %>

and so on the `show.html.erb` there is 
`<a href="<%= @user.my_website %>">Go to my website</a>`

and that works fine

but say the user doesnt input anything in the form for my_website, how would i make it work so that this part`<a href="<%= @user.my_website %>">Go to my website</a>` hides if the user doesnt input my_website

Basically something like this

```
if user puts in my_website, show
 <a href="<%= @user.my_website %>">Go to my website</a>

else
```

show nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is after form submission. You can just use an `if` statement.

```
<% if @user.my_website %>
  <%= link_to "Go to my website", @user.my_website %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, the solution below will not display `"Go to my website"` if the user inputs a bunch of whitespaces for the `my_website` field. `blank?` will return true if @user.my_website is nil or contains an empty string.

```
<% unless @user.my_website.blank? %>
  <%= link_to "Go to my website", @user.my_website %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i am not sure this will work, so maybe try: `"http://#{@user.my_website}"`
i suppose the user doesn't input the `http`

Comment: @Zippie I think it depends on how the user is filling out the field

Comment: yeah, let him decide what's best, just making sure he knows the his options

Comment: Thanks a lot hyngyn, but Zippie good point, how would i make it so that if the user actually enters http:// it would display just "#{@user.my_website}"
but if they enter just the domain name without the http:// how would it show "http://#{@user.my_website}"

Comment: @user2225129 You can look into validations to make sure that your users follow a certain format. This railscasts video might help -- http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3