# How can I DRY up this Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, dry

I'm working in a Rails application, and I've got this Haml repeating about a dozen times. How can I refactor this? I feel like a helper would be great for this, but I'm really not sure what code should go in the helper.

```
- if @object.thing
  .row
    .col-md-12
      .campaign-summary-title Thing
      = render text: @campaign.thing.html_safe
- if @object.thing2
      .row
        .col-md-12
          .campaign-summary-title Thing2
          = render text: @object.thing2.html_safe
```

I found this, but it's not really the same question: [Dont show field if blank Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936967/dont-show-field-if-blank-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). Your partial (`_partial_name.html.haml`) would look like:

```
- if @object[field]
  .row
    .col-md-12
      .campaign-summary-title= field.capitalize
        = render text: @object[field].html_safe
```

That allows you to use this code in different files, calling it like:

```
= render partial: "partial_name", field: "thing"
= render partial: "partial_name", field: "thing2"
```

And in case that there are many fields you could for example write it like :

```
- ["thing", "thing2"].each do |field|
  = render partial: "partial_name", field: field
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
- [:thing, :thing2].each do |thing_sym|
  - if @object.send(thing_sym)
    .row
      .col-md-12
        .campaign-summary-title #not sure what you want here
        = rendertext: @campaign.send(thing_sym).html_safe
```

You'll have to fuss with the title bit as it's unclear how you want to derive `Thing`, `Thing2`, etc.